How to change the collapse direction in a MUI accordion?
I am currently working on changing the collapse direction for a MUI Accordion from being top to bottom to be bottom to top. Is there anyway to implement this in MUI React? if there isn't, is there any alternatives to this behavior?
Thanks in advance.
